# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: after I add ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, nosuchelementexception

I am writing program that moves digits from TextField to TextArea for sorting or shuffling or reversing them. All entered digits have to be save in ArrayList.

At first I create javafx stage with buttons labels and etc. Then I added listeners for buttons and for moving text from TextField to TextArea. I run succefully my program couple times before I assign to store digits in ArrayList. Then I got exception message

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: StoreNumbers.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1778)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:119)
```

I have search on web and on stackoverflow but didn't find something that help me to understand what I am doing wrong. Below my code. Thank you for help in advance for any advices.

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.geometry.Pos;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.*;
 import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
 import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
 import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
 import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
 import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 import java.util.*;

 public class StoreNumbers extends Application {
    private TextField textField = new TextField();
    private TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    StoreNumberPane snPane = new StoreNumberPane();
    List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Button btSort = new Button("Sort");
    Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");
    Button btReverse = new Button("Reverse");
    HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(btSort, btShuffle, btReverse);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    btSort.setOnAction(e -> snPane.sort());
    btShuffle.setOnAction(e -> snPane.shuffle());
    btReverse.setOnAction(e -> snPane.reverse());

    Label label = new Label("Enter a number: ");

    textField.setPromptText("Enter integer");
    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();

    flowPane.getChildren().addAll(label, textField);

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(textArea);

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(textArea);
    pane.setBottom(hBox);
    pane.setTop(flowPane);

    pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            obtainData();
            textField.clear();
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise20_20");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    snPane.requestFocus();
}

    public void displayArray(){

    }

    private void obtainData(){

        String userInput = textField.getText();
        if(userInput != null)

        arrayList.add(userInput);

        textArea.setText(String.format("%s", arrayList));
    }



}

class StoreNumberPane extends Pane{

StoreNumbers storeNumbers = new StoreNumbers();




public void sort(){
    Collections.sort(storeNumbers.arrayList);

}

public void shuffle(){
    Collections.shuffle(storeNumbers.arrayList);
}

public void reverse(){
    Collections.reverse(storeNumbers.arrayList);
}
}
```

Comment: where is your main method?

Comment: This is a javafx application. You don't need main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your application is you are trying to create a new instance of the application class again from the `StoreNumberPane`, even before the old instance has finished instantiating itself.

There should be only one application class instance int eh whole application. So creating a new instance won't help. `JavaFX won't throw an error for it, but it is not the instance you are looking for`

Now, you just need an arraylist in the `StoreNumberPane`, you have many options to get it.

- Make the `ArrayList` as static which can now be easily accessed from anywhere
- Create a method which returns the current instance of the class and use it to access the list
- The last and the best way would be to pass the lsit you want to sort, shuffle or reverse

Your call becomes,

```
btSort.setOnAction(e -> snPane.sort(arrayList));
```

Your method declaration becomes,

```
public void sort(List list) {
    Collections.sort(list);
}
```

`Though I am still not sure, why are you using the`StoreNumberPane`which extends`Pane`. It doesn't do anything that needs Pane to be extended.`

A complete example which sorts string:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StoreNumbers extends Application {
    private TextField textField = new TextField();
    private TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    StoreNumberPane snPane = new StoreNumberPane();
    public List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button btSort = new Button("Sort");
        Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");
        Button btReverse = new Button("Reverse");
        HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(btSort, btShuffle, btReverse);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        btSort.setOnAction(e -> { snPane.sort(arrayList); refreshData(); });
        btShuffle.setOnAction(e -> { snPane.shuffle(arrayList); refreshData(); });
        btReverse.setOnAction(e -> { snPane.reverse(arrayList); refreshData(); });

        Label label = new Label("Enter a number: ");

        textField.setPromptText("Enter String");
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();

        flowPane.getChildren().addAll(label, textField);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(textArea);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(textArea);
        pane.setBottom(hBox);
        pane.setTop(flowPane);

        pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                obtainData();
                textField.clear();
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise20_20");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        snPane.requestFocus();
    }

    public void displayArray() {

    }

    private void obtainData() {
        String userInput = textField.getText();
        if (userInput != null)
            arrayList.add(userInput);
        textArea.setText(String.format("%s", arrayList));
    }

    private void refreshData() {
        textArea.clear();
        textArea.setText(String.format("%s", arrayList));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

class StoreNumberPane extends Pane {

    public void sort(List<String> list) {
        Collections.sort(list);
    }

    public void shuffle(List<String> list) {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
    }

    public void reverse(List<String> list) {
        Collections.reverse(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much you explanation. But I didn't get what you mean by this "The problem with your application is you are trying to create a new instance of the application class again from the StoreNumberPane, even before the old instance has finished instantiating itself." Could you clarify?

Comment: I am trying to show what actually happens in your application `launch` -> StoreNumbers -> StoreNumberPane -> StoreNumbers -> StoreNumberPane ... and this goes on and on.

Comment: I got it. Thank you to answer on my question.

Answer (score -2):

Your extending from class application. By doing so you always need the main function to be declared.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    launch (args);
}
```

Have a look at this simple oracle example...[helloworld](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm)

Comment: Ups ment to point the start method, main is only required in swing app